# When a reader takes on the struggles and emotions of a character in a work of fiction, what is this called?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that describes how a reader emotes with the characters. The reader doesn't empathize with a character, instead he feels the very same emotions as the character coursing through him/her.

Usage in a sentence:

1. John truly **(verb)** with/for this character.
2. John is **(adjective)** of this character.

Comment: Perharps 'paralleled' - the reader paralleled the emotions of the character ?

Comment: Perpetually, single-word-requests must include an example sentence (with a blank for  the requested word) to illustrate how you intende to use the word. Check [this](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11865/warn-people-of-the-rules-for-single-word-requests-before-posting?cb=1) out.

Comment: Can "pathos" be used for this? "1. the quality or power, esp in literature or speech, of arousing feelings of pity, sorrow, etc"

Answer (score 6):

The reader "identifies" with the characters in the book.

> [identify with someone] to feel that you can understand and share someone else’s feelings

-[MacMillan Dictionary online](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/identify-with)

Comment: Hi Mark, welcome to EL&U. This isn't a bad start, but it's too short: the system has flagged it as "low-quality because of its **length** and **content**." An answer on EL&U is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. It's best if you [edit] your answer to provide more information - e.g., add a published definition of the relevant meaning of *identify* (linked to the source) and examples of its use. For further guidance, see [answer] and take the EL&U **[Tour]** :-)

Answer (score 2):

- > The reader **relate**s to the character in the fictional work X.

**relate**  [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/relate)

> make a logical or causal connection; establish or demonstrate a
>   connection between

and

**relate**  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/161807?rskey=99Nt1o&result=2#eid)

> intransitive. With to. To understand or have empathy for; to identify
>   or feel a connection with.

The verb **relate** means "to make a connection." To **connect** to or with is good too.

Answer (score 2):

You could describe the reader's emotions as **[vicarious](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/vicarious)** .. e.g.

"..the reader's **vicarious** joy at the protagonist's return to his family.."

or:

".. the reader **vicariously** experienced the protagonist's joy.."

Answer (score 1):

You might have luck with something like "mirror" in verb form.

"As Joe dug deeper into the novel his horror mirrored that of Dr Aunoir, the doomed narrator."

If you wanted to take it further, perhaps the reader could "inhabit" the character's emotions.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the money with **empathise**.

According to Cambridge Online:

> **Empathise:** *verb:* to be able to understand how someone else feels:
>
> *Example:* It's very easy to empathize with the characters in her books.

I'm sure you could find a slightly more specific word but it would be pretty obscure.